# Android Linking adapter crashing ERROR : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I get the error java.lang.NullPointerException, and I have no clue what to do or how to fix it.

I have 3 fragments creating up a tabhost, and inside fragment b there will be the list view of all the items.

MainActivity

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import tk.delacour.tabdemo.fragments.FragmentB;
import tk.delacour.tabdemo.fragments.FragmentPageAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    ActionBar actionBar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    FragmentPageAdapter ft;
    private Bundle savedInstanceState;

    ListView listView;
    FragmentB baseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            ft = new FragmentPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            viewPager.setAdapter(ft);
            actionBar = getActionBar();
            assert actionBar != null;
            actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Home").setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Shop").setTabListener(this));
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("Contact").setTabListener(this));

            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
            listView.setAdapter(new Adapter(this)); //Error Here.....



            viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int i) {


                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(i);


                    }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

                }



            });

        }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }




}

class SingleRow {
    String codeRef;
    String title;
    String price;
    String description;
    int images;
    SingleRow(String codeRef, String title, String price, String description, int images) {
        this.codeRef = codeRef;
        this.images = images;
        this.title = title;
        this.price = price;
        this.description = description;


    }
}

class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ArrayList<SingleRow> arrayList;
    Context context;

    Adapter(Context contxt) {
        context = contxt;
        arrayList = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();

        Resources res = contxt.getResources();
        String[] codeRef = res.getStringArray(R.array.codeRef);
        String[] title = res.getStringArray(R.array.title);
        String[] price = res.getStringArray(R.array.price);
        String[] descriptions = res.getStringArray(R.array.description);
        int[] images = {R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, R.drawable.pic3, R.drawable.pic4, R.drawable.pic5, R.drawable.pic6, R.drawable.pic7, R.drawable.pic8, R.drawable.pic9, R.drawable.pic10, R.drawable.pic11, R.drawable.pic12, R.drawable.pic13, R.drawable.pic14,};

        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
            arrayList.add(new SingleRow(codeRef[i], title[i], price[i], descriptions[i], images[i]));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        TextView price = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        TextView description = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtDescription);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        SingleRow temp = arrayList.get(position);

        title.setText(temp.title);
        price.setText(temp.price);
        description.setText(temp.description);
        image.setImageResource(temp.images);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Fragment A B and C

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import tk.delacour.tabdemo.R;

/**
 * Created by Christian on 05/10/2014.
 */
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
    }
}


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import tk.delacour.tabdemo.R;

/**
 * Created by Christian on 05/10/2014.
 */
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);


    }



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import tk.delacour.tabdemo.R;

/**
 * Created by Christian on 05/10/2014.
 */
public class FragmentC extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_c, container, false);
    }


}
```

FragmentPageAdapter

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Christian on 05/10/2014.
 */
public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0){
            case 0:
                return new FragmentA();
            case 1:
                return new FragmentB();
            case 2:
                return new FragmentC();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }
}
```

LOGCAT

```
10-10 21:10:58.502  19591-19591/tk.delacour.tabdemo D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
10-10 21:10:58.502  19591-19591/tk.delacour.tabdemo W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42f05500)
10-10 21:10:58.502  19591-19591/tk.delacour.tabdemo E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{tk.delacour.tabdemo/tk.delacour.tabdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at tk.delacour.tabdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5303)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2417)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5390)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: make sure you have `R.id.itemListView` in `activity_main`

Comment: you cant that is the customview fragment with the view pager adapter.

Comment: Then move the code that touches the listview to where you inflate the layout that contains the listview, such as fragment `onCreateView()`.

Comment: ok @laalto i moved  
listView = (ListView)                                                                                 findViewById(R.id.itemListView);
listView.setAdapter(new baseAdapter(this));

To onCreateView but now its showing nothing in FragmentB.

Comment: Use `rootView.findViewById()` on the inflated hierarchy instead of the activity hierarchy with `findViewById()`. Your inflated views are not yet a part of the activity.

Comment: Im sorry, can you please post sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think listview should be in fragment
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    listview = (ListView)v.findViewById....
   return v;
}
```

......
}
create adapter in fragmentB, use listview setAdatper.